# How to disabled picked date in daterangepicker connected to database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, date-range

How to disable date already picked before in PHP 5 and database using MYSQL, and I tried several time but nothing to work, and I tried to make a booking system

```
              <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                <label class="form-control" style="border:none;">Publish Date</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                <input type="text" name="txtPublishDate" id="txtPublishDate" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $PublishDate; ?>" placeholder="Publish Date" />
              </div>
          </div>


<script>
$(function() {
    $('input[name="txtPublishDate"]').daterangepicker({
        opens: 'right'
    }, function(start, end, label) {
        console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input .... <?php echo is_string($PublishDate) ? ' disabled="disabled" readonly' : ''; ?> />
```

Or, don't even put the input based on if you've already picked it. Show the chosen value in a tag like a span instead. Then the JS won't bind to the disabled input.
eg:

```
<?php if !is_string($PublishDate) { ?>
  <input .... />
<?php } else { ?>
  <span><?php echo $PublishDate ?></span>
<?php } ?>
```